# When I press home button on iPhone, my app minimizes instead of close

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

When I press home button, my app minimizes instead of close. When I launch it again, the app launches the last view controller I was on it, instead of return to first view controller. This is my storyboard:

-> A -> B -> C

When pressing home in "C" and launching it again, app stays on "C" instead of "A"

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setEmail:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: Well great for you and your question is? You are aware that this is normal behavior for iOS apps since iOS 4?

Comment: My partner uses iOS4 also and trying their apps, app closes instead of minimizes...

Comment: I want to force app to show the first view controller when I press home button and launch it again...

Comment: Does his iOS device support mutlitasking, if not than the app will be closed.

Comment: Odd to close this as unlikely to help future visitors... as quitting in background is a valid use case (in some apps), and the below answer is perfect for this.  Just say'n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you close the app, it doesn't KILL it, it just suspends it. Unless you set the option to kill it when you close it.

Go to the settings in your .plist and set

`Application does not run in background` to `YES`

This is also the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key

Also, please read the [Apple Documentation For Application Flow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept answers that have helped you (click the checkmark next to the answer) and have a read of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)